# Trying to get property of non-object when i try to $blog->user->name

Tags: laravel

in my model user

```
public function blogs(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Blog');
    }
```

in my model blog

```
  public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
```

in my BlogController

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        $blog = Blog::find($id);
        dd($blog->user->name);
        return view('admin.pages.blogs.show',compact('blog'));
    }
```

database table user ( id,role_id,name)
if role_id  = 1(admin) then result $blog->user->name is null

if role_id = 2(author)  then result $blog->user->name is name of user

how can i fix when role_id  = 1

Comment: `blogs` table need `user_id` did u check .?

Comment: Are you sure that a user with role_id = 1 has a blog?

Comment: yes,i have user_id not null in blogs table

Comment: when i dd($blog->user());  result is null

Comment: Are you sure that a user with role_id = 1 has a blog?

Comment: i don't see how the `role_id` has anything to do with this

Comment: same here.  A piece of info is either missing or there is a misunderstanding by @LinhVu

Comment: @LinhVu What does your blade template logic look like?  Is there anything there?

Comment: in blogs table i have user_id = 1;

Comment: And does your user with id `1` exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `user_id` from `Blog` model.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

UPD. In any case `role_id` does not matter. So you need to make sure DB contains related records. For example:

```
blogs:
id    user_id    text
1     123        '...'

users:
id    name
123   'Linh'
```

Comment: Second param in `belongsTo` method is 'foreign_key', not the local key.

Comment: it will be default use `user_id` for this relationship do to the name of the relationship method, so its the same thing

Comment: `$this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');` by default

Comment: incorrect ... https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one  look at the `Phone` model and its `user` relationship ... "Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with `_id`"

Comment: the wording of 'parent' in those paragraphs makes it harder to understand what it is talking about in the docs unfortunately ... good idea though :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you change `blogs` `users` and `roles` migration.

**blogs migration**

```
Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->bigIncrements('id');
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
      $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
      $table->string('title');
      $table->string('slug')->unique();
      $table->string('image');
      $table->string('body');
      $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(0);
      $table->tinyInteger('is_approved')->default(0);
      $table->integer('view_count')->default(0);
      $table->timestamps();
});
```

**users migration**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->bigIncrements('id');
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->default(2);
      $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
      $table->string('name');
      $table->string('username')->unique();
      $table->string('email')->unique();
      $table->string('password');
      $table->string('image')->default('default.png');
      $table->text('about')->nullable();
      $table->rememberToken();
      $table->timestamps();
});
```

**roles migration**

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->bigIncrements('id');
      $table->string('name');
      $table->string('slug')->unique();
      $table->timestamps();
});
```

**User model**

```
public function blogs(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Blog');
}
```

**Blog model**

```
public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**BlogController**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $blog = Blog::find($id);
    dd($blog->user->name);//check
    return view('admin.pages.blogs.show',compact('blog'));
}
```